# Put previous jump location in other buffer

Tags: split, jumplist

I have multiple interesting buffers in my jumplist, but I would like to view two of them side-by-side. How would you do that? That's the general case of this question.

In my particular case, it is because I have a split next to my file with vim-fugitive, showing diffs of a commit. I want to keep that fugitive buffer open, but change the left split to view the file of a diff fugitive is showing me. So, I can press Enter on a change in fugitive, and it will go to that file (in the git-index), and then I can press C-O to jump back; but now I need to open the next/previous item on the jump list in the other split. Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with simply `2<C-O>` or `<C-O><C-O><C-O>...`?

Comment: each buffer has its own jumplist; I want to move one buffer to the previous item on the jumplist of the other buffer. C-O jumps back to the previous item on the jumplist of the current buffer, in the current buffer.

Comment: Newly created window usually inherits jumplist automatically.

Comment: that doesn't help at all; I mean, I don't want to seem ungrateful, but it seems as if you misread my question. Reading it over and over I don't see any clearer way to explain the problem.

Comment: Ah, so your problem that you don't know how to tell fugitive to open file in split, and so you keep hitting "CR" and "C-O" instead of reading `:h fugitive-navigation-maps`?

Comment: yes, thank you! `o` or `gO` followed by <CR> opens one diff in the split, and the other in the current window.